# POST request works on Safari but not on Chrome and Ionic

Tags: angularjs, cordova, post, ionic-framework

I'm writing a web scraper for a hybrid app. I wrote it using angular. I need to log in to a website to fetch videos. I can log in while on Safari but on Chrome it gives me the Access-Control-Allow-Origin error and I can't change this as the site i'm trying to scrape doesn't provide that header. I've tried disabling web security on Chrome but it still doesn't work. The app works fine in Safari but when I package it in Ionic it doesn't login to the website, and it doesn't throw any error codes. This is what the head of my html page looks like:

```
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">-->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!--don't need angular script because already loaded somewhere else
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="webscrape.js"></script>
```

My POST request looks like this, in the js file:

```
  login: function(token) {
    var request = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://bslsignbank.ucl.ac.uk/accounts/login',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      data: 'csrfmiddlewaretoken=' + token + '&email=stackoverflow%40sto.ac.uk&password=dontworry&next=%2F'
    };
    return $http(request);
```

The POST request seems to work on Safari with any csrf token as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Chrome using below command in run(window key+r) window. It will open a chromebrowser and then try making ajax request from it:

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

With Cordova CLI-5.2, you need to implement whitelist plugin to successfully make ajax requests in Android. Check this [link](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist) for implementing whitelist pluging

Comment: I'm on a mac but I tried the equivalent command and chrome still doesn't work, same error. Already have the whitelist plugin. Changed config to include `<allow-navigation href="*" />` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Use below command from terminal for same: open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --user-data-dir="/var/tmp/Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

Comment: Have you installed whitelist plugin?

Comment: So now Ionic and Chrome work similarly. They both don't log in to the website but they can still get the video urls. The video urls aren't dependent on being logged in, i need to log in for another purpose. But Safari logs in. Do you know why Safari would log in and Chrome wouldn't? Yes i have the whitelist plugin

Comment: Chrome have cross origin policy. And according to that policy chrome doesn't allow cross-origin access by default. So you need to disable the web security to resolve cross origin issue. There are couple of chrome extensions also available to resole cross origin issue but they have some cons like session issue etc. So it's better to disable web security to work proper.

Comment: Chrome and safari both log in now. But Ionic doesn't work. I think this something to do with the website that i'm trying to scrape. For some reason, the mobile version of the website won't let you log in. Only after i click full version (on browser) does it let me log in.

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines in your config.xml and try

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Comment: For some reason, the first line is throwing an error.

Comment: Are you using cloud build or local build?

Comment: I'm not sure but everythings local.

Comment: AAPT: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
But i think the error isn't with Ionic, it's with the website itself. When you first open the website on a mobile browser, it opens a version of the website where login is disabled. To open the full version you click a button on the bottom of the website and then login works. How would i change my code for that? The query in the url is ?flavour=full but the post request won't let me do that, chrome throws an error